# Finding how many distinct equivalence classes there are.

Tags: analysis, relations, equivalence-relations

Define a relation $R$ on the set of all integers $Z$ by $xRy$ ($x$ related to $y$) if and only if $x-y=3k$ for some integer $k$.

I have already verified that this is in fact an equivalence relation. But now I need to find how many distinct equivalence classes there are.

I am confused on how to find how many distinct equivalence classes there are.

Comment: Hint: take any integer, say $0$.  Find all the elements equivalent to $0$.  They form an equivalence class.  Take any integer not in this equivalence class and repeat.  Keep going until there are no more "unused" integers.

Comment: Write $x=3a+r, y=3b+s$ where $r,s$ are the *remainders* when dividing $x,y$ by 3.

Comment: It's easy to answer this when one already knows the answer.   One can ask "gee, what is $[1]$ and realize $[1]=\{y|y-1=3k\}=\{3k+1\}=\{....,-2,1,4,7,...\}$ and then ask what isn't included and realize $[2]=\{3k+2\}$ and $[3]=[0]=\{3k+3\}=\{3k\}$ and get that that covers all and there are $3$ classes.  If one *didn't* know the answer, I guess we'd say the set of classes are $[x_1],[x_2],[x_3],....etc$ where pairwise $x_i\not \sim x_i$ so $x_i-x_j \ne 3k$ and realize that means $x_i=x_j+r$ where $r=1, 2$ and eventually that... it's the classes of remainders.

Answer (score 0):

All equivalence classes are congruent classes of modulo 3. $Cl(0)=\{0, 3, -3, 6, -6,\ldots\}$ $Cl(1) = \{1, -2, 4, -5, 7, \ldots\}$ $Cl(2)=\{2, -1, 5, -4,\ldots\}$

Comment: Can you explain a little more on what you mean? Are equivalence classes the remainders then?

Comment: To construct, start with $Cl(0) = \{m\in \mathbb{Z}:m-0=3k\}$ and continue the process.

Answer (score 0):

For any integer $x$, we can write $x$ in modulo $3$: $x = 3k + r$ where $r$ is the remainder when $x$ divided by $3$. For example: $8 = 2\cdot 3 + 2$. This means $8 - 2 = 3\cdot 2\implies 8 \sim 2$. This means also that $[8]=[2]$. In general: $x - r = 3k \implies x \sim r \implies [x] = [r]$. And we can count the distinct possibilities of $r$. With modulo $3$, there are only $3$ choices for $r$, namely: $0,1,2$. Thus there are $3$ equivalence classes, and they are: $[0] = \{3k: k \in \mathbb{Z}\}, [1] = \{3k+1: k \in \mathbb{Z}\}, [2] = \{3k+2: k \in \mathbb{Z}\}. $